# Mark the end of the file in apache beam/dataflow streaming pipeline and ReadAllFromText

Tags: python, streaming, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Is there any option to achieve in apache beam/dataflow streaming mode (Python SDK) something like this:

- read from PubSub. Message will contain path to GCS file [Easy to do].
- read this file in parallel manner (ReadAllFromText) [Easy to do].
- Some DoFn transformation operating on single rows [Easy to do].
- Something that will tell me that this file has been finished. If file had 100 rows, after 100 rows I would like to see e.g. logging.info("File X is over, had 100 rows").

I am not able to achieve this final point.
The poor alternative is to use `GcsIO.open` to read GCS file inside some DoFn transformation, but this approach has no possibility to be parallelized.

Any ideas appreciated.

Edit:
The reason of this is to achieve some kind of transnationality. I would like to have a control in the flow to for example:

- count valid and invalid rows in each file.
- once all rows of the file are uploaded somewhere, I would like to send pubsub message to other pipeline, for example:

```
{
"filename": "x",
"rows_valid": 100,
"rows_invalid": 44,
"rows_total": 1044
}
```

In this achievable?

Comment: Why do you want this ? Can you explain more the need please ?

Comment: @MazlumTosun I added extra description in my post, hope it helps

Comment: Does this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73862383/apache-beam-read-data-from-gcs-buckets-during-pipeline/73862417#73862417) help you?